# Eclipse, configure files

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, directory

I am using `Eclipse IDE` to write code in `PHP`, but I used `NetBeans`, which is also a very good editor!, However, I came across a doubt, NetBeans, when I created a new project, it generated an `nbproject` folder, with figures from the netbeans, of course, are the project settings, since the eclipse, generates files in the root directory of the project, I wonder if I would do this with eclipse, when I create a project in eclipse, create it creates a directory named 'ecproject' and play the files `'. buildpath'`, `'. project'`, `'. settings'` inside this directory, so it looks *organized* application folder. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This has been discussed quite a long time ago at Eclipse (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76695, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=42875 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=72301)

The last one contains an interesting suggestion, though: Create another project for the .project-Files and just link your sources into that one.